# How to retrieve value of attribute from element in c#

Tags: c#, xpath

I have below html element, and  I want to get the value of attribute "data-productid"

```
<div qa-id="itemImageContainer" class="items__img oli-image js-oli-image zoom_on_hover" ng-class="{'zoom_on_hover': oli.IsNewPreviewEnabled === true}" data-action="edit" data-oli-index="0" data-productid="2940" data-complete="false" data-design-name="" data-tid="27dff633-049f-44c8-bab8-40e3bd533feb" data-productsku="2940">
```

XPath

```
//*[@qa-id = 'itemImageContainer']
```

Answer (score 0):

Most HTML is XML compliant ([a list of some exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39560454/9363973)) so you should be able to parse an `XElement` from your string and get the value like so:

```cs
var element = XElement.Parse(divString);
// The return value of 'Attribute(...)' can be null, so maybe do null checking
var dataProductId = element.Attribute("data-productid").Value;
```

If you run into some HTML that is not valid XML, you'll probably need something like the [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) to properly parse your HTML. Using it your code would like this:

```cs
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.Load(htmlString);
var div = html.DocumentNodes.SelectNodes("//*[@qa-id = 'itemImageContainer']").LastOrDefault();
// Maybe check if its null
var dataProductId = div.Attributes["data-productid"].Value;
```

I don't have a lot of experience working with XPath, so I got my example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21236396/9363973) answer